# Getting laravel is not recognized as an internal or external command when creating new project

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

Respected all,

I am a beginner in Laravel 10. I installed the composer successfully. When I am using `composer global require laravel/installer` command, getting error *Nothing to modify in lock file* and when I am using `laravel new first-project` again showing error like this.

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try to update your composer

```
composer self-update
```

If not try reinstalling composer to your unit

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

try also checking your php version

Comment: I am using the latest version of the php https://prnt.sc/OkvTbTJeuwLf 8.2.4. and when i add the composer self-update command then saying that you having the latest composer https://prnt.sc/D4pKEuaXGoya, It is saying like that https://prnt.sc/1X1DV9-wegQh it should say like that https://prnt.sc/7OxDKiBBm-na. so please resolve this one.